# ¿amigos, Como podría hacer este mismo programa pero con objeto (POO)?

Tags: java, poo

```
package imprimirvocales;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Imprimirvocales {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner text = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Por favor escriba un texto: ");
        String palabra;
        palabra = text.nextLine();

        char arreglo []  = palabra.toCharArray(); 

        int conta =0;  

        for (int count=0;count<arreglo.length;count++){
            if ((palabra.charAt(count)=='a')|| (palabra.charAt(count)=='A')||(palabra.charAt(count)=='e')
            ||(palabra.charAt(count)=='E')|| (palabra.charAt(count)=='i') || (palabra.charAt(count)=='I') 
            || (palabra.charAt(count)=='o') || (palabra.charAt(count)=='O') || (palabra.charAt(count)=='u')
            || (palabra.charAt(count)=='U')){
            conta++; 
            }          
        }  
          System.out.println("\nhan sido ingresados: "+conta+" vocales"); 

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Que es lo que deseas sea un objeto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que necesitas que se encapsule el proceso en una clase y que utlizes metodos para calcular las vocales no?

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String mensaje = "Hola Mundo";
        ImprimirVocales ivocales = new ImprimirVocales(mensaje);
        System.out.println(ivocales.getNumeroVocales());
    }
}

class ImprimirVocales{

    private String str;

    public ImprimirVocales(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public int getNumeroVocales() {
        int contador = 0;
        for(char c: str.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I' || c == 'O' || c == 'U' || 
                c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u') {
                contador++;
            }
        }
        return contador;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una Java mainclass:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication3;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author villa.kelly
 */
public class JavaApplication3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner text = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Por favor escriba un texto: ");
    String palabra;
    palabra = text.nextLine();
    Contador contador = new Contador(palabra);
    int conta=contador.contar();

      System.out.println("\nhan sido ingresados: "+conta+" vocales"); 

    }
}//fin
```

Que use la Java class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication3;

/**
 *
 * @author villa.kelly
 */
public class Contador {

    public Contador(String input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    private String input;

    /**
     * Get the value of input
     *
     * @return the value of input
     */
    public String getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of input
     *
     * @param input new value of input
     */
    public void setInput(String input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public int contar(){
        String palabra = this.input;
        char arreglo []  = palabra.toCharArray(); 
        int conta =0;  

    for (int count=0;count<arreglo.length;count++){
        if ((palabra.charAt(count)=='a')|| (palabra.charAt(count)=='A')||(palabra.charAt(count)=='e')
        ||(palabra.charAt(count)=='E')|| (palabra.charAt(count)=='i') || (palabra.charAt(count)=='I') 
        || (palabra.charAt(count)=='o') || (palabra.charAt(count)=='O') || (palabra.charAt(count)=='u')
        || (palabra.charAt(count)=='U')){
        conta++; 
        }          
    }  
      return conta; 
    }
    }
```

Lo corres y listo, me comentas qué tal te va!